# how to retrieve multiple selected values from <select multiple > in java code?

Tags: java, jsp, select, servlets

code is below:

```
<select name="merTransactionTypeId" class="cbox"  multiple>
  <!--
  <option value="0" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"0".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>All</option>
  --> 
  <option value="2" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"2".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>Reload</option>
  <option value="1" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"1".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>Sale</option>
  <option value="5" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"5".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>CCMS_Recharge</option>             
  <option value="6" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"6".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>Loyalty_Award</option>      
  <option value="7" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"7".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>Loyalty_Redeem</option>     
  <option value="16" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"16".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>FCC_Reload</option>
  <option value="11" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"11".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>Tracking</option>
  <option value="12" <%=request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId")!=null?"12".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("merTransactionTypeId"))?"selected":"":""%>>Fund_Transfer_From_Card</option>                  
</select>
```

i am trying to retrieve values from dropdown with code in scriplet as

```
<% String[] selectedTransactionTypes = request.getParameterValues("merTransactionTypeId"); %>
```

...but it's returning null.  Please help me out.

Comment: give the code of the button that's submitting the form and the form itself.

Comment: Please do not use tabs in text dumped to SO.  For more info, see the Markdown reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Check that you don't call request.getInputStream or request.getReader before request.getParameterValues

Comment: @Bozho form submit is working fine for other fields

Comment: they might work, but that doesn't mean the code you have missed out isn't hiding the root of the problem.

Comment: so, what was the exact problem? BalusC accepted answer suggested a number of possible problems, which one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the listbox isn't enclosed in the same `<form>`, or there's even no means of a `<form>`, or maybe you tried to access it at the wrong moment (e.g. *before* form submit), or maybe there's a typo in the parameter name (use `getParameterNames()` to view them all).

That said, I strongly recommend you to leave the old fashioned scriptlets aside and go ahead with a servlet class to preprocess and postprocess the request and taglibs/EL to control the flow and access data in JSP. It will make your code much cleaner.